# useSelector updates twice when createAsyncThunk dispatches event fulfilled

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to redux toolkit and react. But I'm trying to follow the redux toolkit slicer methodology.

My slice:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const axios = require("axios");
export const fetchR = createAsyncThunk(
  "fetchR",
  async (teamId) => {
    console.log(teamId);
    var data = await axios.get(url);

    return data.data;
  }
);
export const rSlice = createSlice({
  name: "slice",
  initialState: {
    data: { count: 0, data: [] },
    loading: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    setR: (state, action) => {},
    getR: (state, action) => {},
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchR.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = "loading";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchR.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
      state.loading = "loaded";
    });
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setR, getR } = rSlice.actions;

export default rSlice.reducer;
```

My component that calls fetchR the createAsyncThunk.

```
  <IconButton
    onClick={() => {
      dispatch(fetchR("FU"));
    }}
    type="submit"
    sx={{ p: "10px" }}
    aria-label="search"
  >
    <SearchIcon />
  </IconButton>
```

My component that listens to state change for rSlice.

```
const MainSub = () => {
  const rList = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log(state.res);
    return state.res;
  }, shallowEqual);
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MainSub;
```

My console.log:

```
FU
MainSub.js:6 
{res: {…}}
res: {data: {…}, loading: 'loading'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
MainSub.js:6 
{res: {…}}
res: {data: {…}, loading: 'loaded'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
MainSub.js:6 
{res: {…}}
res: {data: {…}, loading: 'loaded'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Notice that the console log in MainSub runs twice when createAysncThunk dispatches fulfilled. I'm not sure what could cause this to run twice. **Looking at my network traffic, there is only ONE get request made.** So I know that I'm not making multiple requests. Our thunk dispatches an event to pending and fulfilled once. But useSelector thinks the state was changed twice when Thunk dispatches to fulfilled. Again this console log is happening in our MainSub component. Any help would be appreciated Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the selector will get run twice - once in the Redux subscription callback after the action itself is dispatched (so it runs *outside* of React), but then potentially again inside the component itself during render.  This is due to an implementation detail of `useSelector`.

As a side note, **you should never write `useSelector(state => state)` - that will *always* cause the component to re-render *any* time the root state changes!**  Instead, you should [always select the smallest piece of state this component needs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#using-multiple-selectors-in-a-component).

Comment: In this case I would want the component to re-render any time the root changes for this specific store. Since all the store's data pertains to this component. 

Are you referring to shallowEqual to mitigate re rendering if no data has changed?

Comment: Normally a Redux root state contains many "slice states" nested inside, like `{posts, comments, users}`.  You wouldn't want a component to re-render when _any_ of those change - just when a _specific piece_ changes.  It sounds like you may be very early in building the app, and only have one section of state. I would still recommend nesting that data as `state.someSlice`, rather than using the slice as the "root state" itself. You would need to make that change anyway as the app grows and you add more slices.

Comment: makes total, sense. On another note, I'm update the post using shallowEqual. But with that code, there's still re-rendering happening although the data hasn't changed.

Comment: That's actually pretty much my point :) **Your state has been updated, therefore it is _not_ equal to the old state!**  Immutable updates require making copies of the entire nested state path that has to be updated, and that includes making a copy of the root state object.  **The root state object will _never_ be equal if there were _any_ state updates at all**.

Comment: The data inside the state hasn't changed. So isn't shallowEqual supposed to prevent rerender if the data in the state hasn't changed? I again modified the code so that I'm using state.res

Comment: I'm very confused, tbh.  You said you "updated a post".  By definition, that means the state changed.  At this point it might be worth opening up a follow-up question, or asking over in the Reactiflux Discord ( https://www.reactiflux.com ).

Comment: My Mistake, I updated this stackoverflow post. I modified the code in my original post.

Comment: Or I mean't that I updated the code in the Original Post. Not that I updated a post/state.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I'm still confused here, though. You say "the data inside the state hasn't changed". Are you _sure_ about that? Because if you're dispatching actions, and those actions are updating the state, then... the state will have changed and it won't be equal at all any more.  I'd suggested looking at the Redux DevTools and inspecting the "Diffs".  Most likely it will show that state changes _are_ happening when you dispatch.

Comment: I'll look into it. In the console.log section of my Original Post you can see the data DOES change from data.loading = "loading" to data.loading = "loaded". (console.log one => console.log two). But you'll see the 3rd console.log where data.loading = "loaded". That's why I'm unsure why dispatch event for that slice is happening again when the data didn't change. data.loading is still equal to "loaded" and data.data didn't change as well (I know for a fact).

Comment: At this point it's hard to say specifically without seeing the actual code running to inspect it myself.  If you can put together a CodeSandbox that shows the issue, or use https://replay.io to record the app doing this and link the replay, I might be able to take a look.  For the record, the _selector_ probably will run at least one more time than than the number of times the component actually renders.